# Fire onChange event only if Promise resolves in the onChange event

Tags: reactjs, events, promise, onchange

```
   const validate(id){
retun new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
axioscall()
.then((res)=> resolve(res))
.catch((err)=>reject(err))
}}
```

I have above Promise. and I am trying to call the onChange event only if my promise resolves or throw error that is rejected by my promise

```
   <checkbox onChange={(e)=>
validate(id)
.then((result) => result && handleChecked(e,id))
.catch((err)=>showError(err))/>
```

Error is thrown successfully but when promise resolves handleChecked event is not successful. I mean the checkbox is not checked.

Error is thrown successfully but when promise resolves handleChecked event is not successful. I mean the checkbox is not checked. What is the issue.. if I write like below Event is fired and checkbox is checked but how to handle failure scenario to show error..How can I modify above code to handle success and failure scenarios?

```
   <checkbox onChange={(e)=>
validate(id) && handleChecked(e,id))
/>
```

Comment: Your `validate()` function is an anti-pattern.  It can just be `return axioscall(...)`.  That's all you need.  That returns the promise directly.  No need to wrap it in a `new Promise(...)`.

Comment: You _must_ read [What is the explicit Promise constructor anti-pattern and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 1):

you can make the input controlled using state.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(false)

    const handleChange = async () => {
        const isValid = await validate(id)

        if(isValid) {
            setValue(prev => !prev)
        }
    }

    <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} checked={value} />
}
```

PS. to make an HTTP request it is better to use a third-party library like `react-query` or `swr` which gives you helpers to track the request, show the loader to the user, handle errors, and much more